# Count items in datasource of gridview (.net)

Tags: .net, gridview, count, datasource

I have a GridView and bind a list to it:

```
List<T> items = T.GetItems();

GridView.DataSource = items.OrderBy(x => x.SomeValue);
GridView.DataBind();
```

Now in the process of databinding, I would like to access the total number of items in the datasource.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //access total number of datasource items
}
```

GridView.Rows or GridView.DataKeys is no help because the gridview is being built at this point. Of course, I could use items.Count() but I would prefer to access the underlying datasource directly.

**Update**

The solutions posted work without the OrderBy statement which I included later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   var count = ((ICollection<T>)GridView.DataSource).Count;
}
```

Comment: I get an error (try to translate): "Object of type System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[T,System.String] cannot be cast to type "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]"

Comment: Then you are **not** using a `List<T>` as you have in your question. If you are using a Linq2Sql datasource try adding a `ToList()` at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could access the count of items by doing something like below:

```
      int count = (GridView1.DataSource as List<T>).Count;
```

Hope this Helps!!

Edit 1:

Added full method used.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        int count = (GridView1.DataSource as List<string>).Count;

    }
```

Comment: No, I get an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of object"

Comment: Here, "GridView1" is the ID of the grid I was using. Provide your ID there and "T" is the type of list that you are trying to bind. Please let me know if this doesn't work as it is working for me.

Comment: It doesn´t work. I have changed everything to my controls and types. Can you show your total code? Will quit now.

Answer (score 0):

With my update included, the items count can be accessed with

```
var count = ((IEnumerable<T>)GridView.DataSource).Count();
```